# Piping a command through a color filter

Tags: bash, terminal, colors

Does something like this exist in Unix?

```
$ echo "this should show in red" | red
$ echo "this should show in green" | green
$ echo "this should show in blue" | blue
```

Here I don't mean for literal color code text to come up (to be pasted in a file, for example). I just mean for the text to actually show up in the terminal as that color. Is this possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a little script that does just that. Save this as `color` in a directory in your `$PATH` (for example, `~/bin` if that's in your `$PATH`):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Term::ANSIColor; 

my $color=shift;
while (<>) {
    print color("$color").$_.color("reset");
}
```

Then, pass your text through the script, giving `.` as the pattern to match and specifying a color:

[image: screenshot of a terminal running the script]

The supported colors depend on the abilities of your terminal. For more details, see the [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/Term/ANSIColor.html#Supported-Colors) of the `Term::ANSIColor` package.

Comment: Is there a list of colors that are valid to pass in somewhere?

Comment: @George that depends on your setup. If you have an RGB-capable terminal, you can even use things like `rgb001`, `rgb123` etc. See http://perldoc.perl.org/Term/ANSIColor.html#Supported-Colors for more details.

Comment: I don't know perl. Why doesn't `color rgb012` work and give me some kind of teal/turquoise color?

Answer (score 24):

You'd use [`tput`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tput.1.html) for that:

```
tput setaf 1
echo This is red
tput sgr0
echo This is back to normal
```

This can be used to build a pipe:

```
red() { tput setaf 1; cat; tput sgr0; }
echo This is red | red
```

The basic colours are respectively black (0), red (1), green, yellow, blue, magenta, cyan and white (7). You'll find all the details in the [`terminfo(5)` manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/terminfo.5.html).

Answer (score 7):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload colors; colors
for color (${(k)fg})
  eval "$color() {print -n \$fg[$color]; cat; print -n \$reset_color}"
```

And then:

```
$ echo "while" | blue
while
```

Answer (score 2):

**(as discussed in comments, [use `tput`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/276475/231543) instead if you have it)**

Using bourne shell and `echo` (built-in) command which understands the ANSI escape `\e` with `-e` option:

```bsh
black()  { IFS= ; while read -r line; do echo -e '\e[30m'$line'\e[0m'; done; }
red()    { IFS= ; while read -r line; do echo -e '\e[31m'$line'\e[0m'; done; }
green()  { IFS= ; while read -r line; do echo -e '\e[32m'$line'\e[0m'; done; }
yellow() { IFS= ; while read -r line; do echo -e '\e[33m'$line'\e[0m'; done; }
blue()   { IFS= ; while read -r line; do echo -e '\e[34m'$line'\e[0m'; done; }
purple() { IFS= ; while read -r line; do echo -e '\e[35m'$line'\e[0m'; done; }
cyan()   { IFS= ; while read -r line; do echo -e '\e[36m'$line'\e[0m'; done; }
white()  { IFS= ; while read -r line; do echo -e '\e[37m'$line'\e[0m'; done; }

echo '    foo\n    bar' | red
```

or, more generic shell script (say, `/usr/local/bin/colorize`):

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

usage() {
    echo 'usage:' >&2
    echo '  some-command | colorize {black, red, green, yellow, blue, purple, cyan, white}' >&2
    exit 1
}

[ -z "$1" ] && usage

case $1 in
    black)  color='\e[30m' ;;
    red)    color='\e[31m' ;;
    green)  color='\e[32m' ;;
    yellow) color='\e[33m' ;;
    blue)   color='\e[34m' ;;
    purple) color='\e[35m' ;;
    cyan)   color='\e[36m' ;;
    white)  color='\e[36m' ;;
    *) usage ;;
esac

IFS=
while read -r line; do
    echo -e $color$line'\e[0m'
done
```

`IFS=` is needed to prevent whitespace trimming (see [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_05) for details).

[image: how IFS works]

Comment: I advise to prefer using `tput`.

Comment: This is completely non-portable solution. I mean you should adhere to POSIX.

Comment: Sure, if we could.
It's intended to be used on embedded systems or rescue environments like busybox.
I decided to write this answer because I believe these code snippets are useful in some situations -- at least for busybox users and for me, who had to output colors only with shell's built-in commands on an embedded environment today.

Comment: forgot to say that ordinary busybox doesn't have tput.