# How to print a pattern of text in color?

Tags: sed, colors

```
RED='\033[0;31m'
NC='\033[0m' # No Color
var='I /love Stack Over/flow'
```

I am trying to print a portion of text using regex in color but it's not working.

```
 echo $var | sed "s=\(.*/\)\(.*\)=\${RED}\2\${NC}="
```

output :

```
${RED}flow${NC}
```

Comment: OK, i was able to get this using `eval echo -e $(echo $var | sed "s=\(.*/\)\(.*\)=\1\${RED}\2\${NC}=")`

Comment: Relevant (perhaps even a duplicate): [Piping a command through a color filter](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/276471)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd not offer to use `eval` if there are many other ways to do the task

```
RED='\\033[0;31m'
NC='\\033[0m' # No Color
echo -e "$(sed "s=[^/]\+$=${RED}&${NC}=" <<<$var)"
```

Due to use `\` inside **sed** you should escape *escape character* - `\\` or use `Esc` by itself to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> followed <kbd>Esc</kbd>